# How to get the IP address of a Samsung Smart TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I am creating an application for a Samsung Smart TV. In my app, I need to get the Smart TV's IP address. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: did you read the Smart TV docs ?

Comment: you could scan DLNA on your network and retrieve the ID and TVName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the SEF NETWORK to do that, make sure you're include this line in index.html

```
<object id='pluginObjectNetwork'    classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NETWORK'    style='opacity:0.0; background-color:#000000;width:0px;height:0px;'></object>
```

Then somewhere in your code you can use function:

```
var GetIPAddress = function(){
    var network = document.getElementById('pluginObjectNetwork');
    return network.GetIP(network.GetActiveType());  
};
```

More information can be read at samsung docs: http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/sef_plugin_network.html

Answer (score 0):

For Tizen TV, you can get IP address from webapis, i.e.,

```
webapis.network.getIp()
```

will return you the IP address of the device.

Include webapi's in your index.html as :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js"></script>
```

You can find more details related to Network of Tizen TV on the below mentioned Link:

http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/network-api